# Camunda workflow started from Message Events repeats three times upon exception

Tags: java, asynchronous, exception, bpmn, camunda

**Background :**

I have three bpmn diagrams

1. DMTMain.bpmn
2. DMTSub.bpmn
3. DMTTst.bpmn

These are the service Tasks for them - screen shots

**1. DMTMain.bpmn**

[image]

**2. DMTSub.bpmn**

[image]

**3. DMTTst.bpmn**

[image]

First *DMTMain.bpmn* is called using the implementation mentioned in below **Code#1**.

For that, processId of DMTMain.bpmn is also passed.

Then in the *MainMsg* service task of the *DMTMain.bpmn*, we call *DMTSub.bpmn* using the *startProcessInstanceByMessage()* method as mentioned in below **Code#2**. 
(Note that DMTSub.bpmn is starting as a MessageEvent).

So, process starting in DMTSub.bpmn runs asynchronously as our expected behaviour. (That's why we used MessageStartEvent for DMTSub.bpmn)

---

**Issue :**

In our situation there can be **various errors throwing from DMTTst.bpmn** process including Camunda Engine related errors.

- eg :  Unknown property used in expression: ${TstRunX}. Cause: Cannot resolve identifier 'TstRunX'

This is **expected behavior** as we are working on the caller framework (eg : including DMTMain and DMTSub etc).

So, the issue is,
when the DMTTst.bpmn throws these like errors although they are caught at SubTst, **only SubOut1** service task in DMTSub.bpmn executes after SubTst and it **goes back to begining (SubParse)** of the DMTSub.bpmn printing errors mentioned in Error#1 **without executing SubOut2 and SubOut3**.

This repeats exactly **three times**. It should be because of [this](https://forum.camunda.org/t/retry-a-service-task-on-an-error/16902/6) and could be changed the retry with [this](https://liquidocs.io/76e494d4-6bbd-439f-acf7-a1c9afb0987a)

1. SubParse
2. SubTst
3. Exception at DMTTst.bpmn
4. SubOut1
5. SubParse
6. SubTst
7. Exception at DMTTst.bpmn
8. SubOut1
9. SubParse
10. SubTst
11. Exception at DMTTst.bpmn
12. SubOut1

---

**Expected behaviour :**

If there are any error thrown from the DMTTst.bpmn, it should be able **to catch at the SubTst** (or equalant place) and proceed **to SubOut2 and SubOut3 without going to the begining**

Actually I know that we can invoke DMTTst.bpmn using CallActivity also. But we changed to this since we want to catch the exceptions.

1. SubParse
2. SubTst
3. Exception at DMTTst.bpmn
4. SubOut1
5. SubOut2
6. SubOut3

---

**Code #1**

```
ProcessEngine defaultProcessEngine = BpmPlatform.getProcessEngineService().getDefaultProcessEngine();
RuntimeService runtimeService = defaultProcessEngine.getRuntimeService();
ProcessInstanceWithVariables processInstanceWithVariables = null;

try {

     processInstanceWithVariables = runtimeService
                .createProcessInstanceByKey(processId)
                .setVariables(execution.getVariables())
                .executeWithVariablesInReturn();

        VariableMap variableMap = processInstanceWithVariables.getVariables();


} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Code #2**

```
public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {

    try {

        RuntimeService runtimeService = execution.getProcessEngineServices().getRuntimeService();
        runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByMessage("dmtSub", execution.getVariables());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Error#1:**

> 15:09:15,996 WARN  [org.camunda.bpm.engine.jobexecutor] ENGINE-14006
>   Exception while executing job f1377b93-91d8-11ea-b41b-0242c2113c7d: :
>   org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: Process engine
>   persistence exception     at
>   org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.rethrow(CommandInvocationContext.java:151)
>     at
>   org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.close(CommandContext.java:178)
>     at
>   org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:116)
>     at
>   org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.JtaTransactionInterceptor.execute(JtaTransactionInterceptor.java:61)
>     at
>   org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:70)
>     at
>   org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:33)
>     at
>   org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobHelper.executeJob(ExecuteJobHelper.java:51)
>   ....
>   ....
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031070: Transaction
>   cannot proceed: STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK    at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.checkTransactionActive(WrapperDataSource.java:248)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransactionActive(WrappedConnection.java:1933)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkStatus(WrappedConnection.java:1948)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransaction(WrappedConnection.java:1922)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:452)

---

**Edit :**

Noted that this happens even we cal the DMTSub.bpmn through CallActivity or MessageEndEvent via normal service task.

And we have tried different ways like start DMTTst workflow with another process engine, catch the exception thrown in SubTst in Error End Event in DMTSub workflow also but no luck. Now trying options mentioned in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/camunda-bpm-users/IOCeVEiwOAE)

Answer (score 1):

Found couple of approaches that close to the expected solution.

**Control the retry** :

You can control the retry by putting the `failedJobRetryTimeCycle` property in your `standalone.xml` file as mentioned below.

The pattern relevant to the [ISO_8601 standard for repeating time intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Repeating_intervals).

```
<property name="failedJobRetryTimeCycle">R0/PT5S</property>
```

Or you can specify that in the service task / start event itself using the Retry Time Cycle under Job Configuration

[image]

---

**Catching error and continuation** :

This can be done in two ways.

1. Adding **a Boundry Error Event to entire DMTTst workflow**.
   [image]
2. Call the **DMTTst as a CallActivity and add a Boundry Error Event to that** and let it flow through to the next task

[image]

**Note :** But in both cases better to add the Error Code as java.lang.Exception as mentioned below. Then it will catch any exception which is subclass of that. eg : Java exception, unrecognized BPMN property etc.

[image]

**References :**

- [Camunda BPM Online Training Error Management](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyS0pOlx2-s)
- [5 Camunda advanced topics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFY1UuiCVl4)